# Equation for Gaussian kernel's effect on a frequency's amplitude

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

Applying a Gaussian blur/kernel with a sigma of $\sigma_{gau}$ to a sine/cosine wave of frequency $f_{sin}$ will cause what percent reduction in the amplitude $p_{amp}$ (not power) of the sine wave?

[Wikipedia gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter#Digital_implementation) this equation $f_c = \sqrt{ln(c)}*\sigma_f$ with an unclear wording on what $c$ is that I think says $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} = p_{amp}$ => $c = \frac{1}{{p_{amp}}^2}$. This would make the equation (Though I'm not sure its correct):

$f_{sin} = \sqrt{ln(c)}*\sigma_{gau}$

$\sqrt{ln(c)} = \frac{f_{sin}}{\sigma_{gau}}$

$c = e^{\frac{{f_{sin}}^2}{{\sigma_{gau}}^2}}$

$\frac{1}{{p_{amp}}^2} = e^{\frac{{f_{sin}}^2}{{\sigma_{gau}}^2}}$

$p_{amp} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{\frac{{f_{sin}}^2}{{\sigma_{gau}}^2}}}} = e^\frac{-{f_{sin}}^2}{2{\sigma_{gau}}^2}$

And if you are a lost soul on google that equation in terms of percent reduction in power $p_{pow}$ is
$p_{pow} = e^\frac{-{f_{sin}}^2}{{\sigma_{gau}}^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for $\phi$ normalized Gaussian kernel (i.e. centered normal density with standard deviation $\sigma$)
$$(e^{ix \alpha} * \phi)(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{iy \alpha}e^{-(y-x)^2/(2\sigma^2)}dy=e^{ix\alpha-\alpha^2\sigma^2/2}$$
So
$$\begin{aligned}(\sin(x\alpha) * \phi)(x)&=\frac{1}{2i}\bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{iy \alpha}e^{-(y-x)^2/(2\sigma^2)}dy-\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-iy \alpha}e^{-(y-x)^2/(2\sigma^2)}dy\bigg)=\\
&=e^{-\alpha^2\sigma^2/2}\sin(x\alpha)\end{aligned}$$
The net percentage change in amplitude is then $e^{-\alpha^2\sigma^2/2}-1$.

Comment: That doesn't seem right because as $\alpha$ (what I was calling $f_{sin}$) gets larger and $\sigma$ says the same you get a larger reduction which is the opposite as expected. Are you sure it isn't $e^{-\alpha^2/2\sigma^2} - 1$

Comment: @ChristopherPratt the first equation is the [characteristic function (CF) of the Gaussian law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Fourier_transform_and_characteristic_function), which is well known.

Comment: @ChristopherPratt it is possible that you parametrize the Gaussian function differently, and the result with $1/\sigma$ as standard deviation is basically the same with inverted $\sigma$.

Comment: I believe you're correct. I was wrongly thinking period not frequency. For the lost souls on google the equation would be: 
$amp_{new} = amp_{old} * e^{-{f_{sin}}^2{\sigma_{gau}}^2/2}$